# Content Security Policy allow inline style without unsafe-inline

Tags: css, content-security-policy

Using content security policy without style-src 'unsafe-inline' how do you allow styles like this?

```html
<span style="font-size: 16px;">Hello</span>
```

I've tried adding a nonce to them and adding that nonce to the CSP header but that doesn't seem to work

```html
<span style="font-size: 16px;" nonce="0611873de7e2db5985c289fdfa946caee2ae1860">Hello</span>
```

```html
"style-src 'nonce-0611873de7e2db5985c289fdfa946caee2ae1860' 'self'"
```

Is there any way to do this without adding the 'unsafe-inline' directive??

Answer (score 5):

According to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=855326#c35 nonces for style attributes isn't supported

Answer (score -3):

a common workaround for this issue is to write the inline-style (or inline-script) data to an input tag:

```
<input id="my-font-size" type="hidden" value="16" />
```

or in HTML5:

```
<input id="my-id" data-font-size="16" />
```

and process the data via an external included JavaScript (to avoid violating "script-src" csp):

```
$('span').css('font-size', $('#my-id').data('font-size'));
```

Comment: this would still be blocked

Comment: Actually it isn't, but you'd still be better off writing a <style> tag and adding the nonce to that.

Comment: jquery's `.css` adds style changes to the active DOM, and thus avoids the CSP issue. However as Sora pointed out, if you have to dynamically add something to the html, its best to not further complicate things by post-processing in javascript, but rather just dynamically add the css in a nonce'd style block with a custom css class for that page render.